# How to make multiple updates to a string in a loop?

Tags: string, flutter

I am wanting to update a string with markup for selected words. Those selected words at in a list. I am iterating over the list and replacing the work in the string with markup.

However, each loop replaces the entire string. I have been at this for a while and need another perspective.

```
//String to be markedup
mainText = "Hi there how are you";

//List of words to be marked up are
distinctWords = ['Hi', 'are', 'you'];

 //Iterate though words to me marked up
distinctWords.forEach((word) {
  updatedString = mainText.replaceFirst(RegExp(word), '$word`'); 
 });

 print(updatedString);
```

**What is an approach to this that would work to ensure that all three words are updated in a single string?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you should update the `updatedString` like so:

```
//String to be markedup
mainText = "Hi there how are you";

//List of words to be marked up are
distinctWords = ['Hi', 'are', 'you'];
updatedString = mainText;                                             // <- added
 //Iterate though words to me marked up
distinctWords.forEach((word) {
  updatedString = updatedString.replaceFirst(RegExp(word), '$word`'); // <- edited
 });

 print(updatedString);
```

or

```
//String to be markedup
mainText = "Hi there how are you";

//List of words to be marked up are
distinctWords = ['Hi', 'are', 'you'];
 //Iterate though words to me marked up
distinctWords.forEach((word) {
mainText = mainText;
  updatedString = mainText.replaceFirst(RegExp(word), '$word`'); // <- edited
 });

 print(updatedString);
```

Comment: Hmm. Maybe Im missing something, but how will this have the outcome of "'\`hi\` there how \`are\` \`you\` '"  it seems to be missing the input of mainText?

Comment: sorry, you are right, it should be `updatedString = mainText;`

Comment: Actually just realised the mainText = updatedString; needs be in the loop. If you update your answer i can approve it